# simulating tail -1 command by using grep command

Tags: regex, unix, grep, command, tail

I want to simulate `tail -1` command using `grep` i.e. I want to print the last line of the file using grep. It can be done easily using `sed` or `awk`. but I couldn't find any option with grep

Comment: Why would you try to make some into something else? Does your system not have `tail`, `sed` or `awk`?  `grep` is not made for this.

Comment: grep is for finding a regexp in a file and printing the matching line (`g/re/p`), not for selecting lines based on their position in a file. You're trying to use the wrong tool for the job, you already know a selection of right tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why on earth you want to do that ?**  There are better tools for this task as all are suggesting.

This is the solution you wanted :

```
grep "^" -n filename | grep -Po "(?<=^$(grep -c "^" filename):)(.*)"
```

The trick is to display all lines with line numbers (-n option).
Then match the line preceding the line count of the file.
The `grep -c "^" filename` part gives the line count.
The `-P` allows to use PCRE since a positive lookbehind match is needed.

If you don't have access to `-P`(I doubt it), use another filtering like follows although it won't work for lines containing `:` character :

```
grep "^" -n filename | grep "^$(grep -c "^" filename):" | grep -o "[^:]*$"
```

The reason behind this post is to show that this can be done only using `grep`.

***Moral :* ! ( It's highly recommended )**